# Attribute Error within a for loop? will not return key as attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, attributeerror

I have tried converting key to a string or reassigning key to another variable. Key will return an attribute within sample, but key is not being seen as sample_name...

```
for key in samples[1].__dict__:
    print(key)
    for row in samples:
        print(row.key)

Output:
sample_name
Traceback (most recent call last):
print(row.key)
AttributeError: 'sample' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Comment: You should use `getattr` when your attribute is presented as a string: `getattr(row, key)`

Comment: Perhaps you want `getattr(row,key)`?

Comment: To clarify... `print(getattr(row, key))` and you can do `if hasattr(row, key)` to skip the cases where it doesn't exist

Comment: What are you trying to do? Using `__dict__` is most likely not what you want to be doing for whatever it is. And using `getattr` won't help as if you're trying to get values via the `dict` object, you need `[]`/`__getitem__` anyway...

Comment: are you doing this in django ?

Comment: I am trying to go through a vector of class instances and write their values into a csv. @JonClements

Comment: @viveksyngh I am just running python 3 in sublime IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `row.key`, you are trying to look up the `'key'` attribute on `row`. This is equivalent to doing `getattr(row, 'key')`. Since `row` has no `'key'` attribute, this produces an error. To dynamically look up an attribute when you have a string for the attribute name, use `getattr(row, key)` and since `key = 'sample_name'`, this is equivalent to `getattr(row, 'sample_name')`. Notice the lack of quotes around `key` in the first usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the following code helps you:

```
for key in samples[1].__dict__:
    print(key)
    for row in samples:
        print getattr(row, key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i've spent a little time to figure out what you want.

`samples` is a list. Each object in list `samples` is a class instance with few attribute. And you want to output their value of each attribute?

If I'm right you may try

```
for each in samples:
    for key in each.__dict__:
        try:
            print(each.key)
        except AttributeError, Argument:
            print('AttributeError')
            print(Argument)
```

However I don't think it's a good idea to use `__dict__`. Give more info about you problem might help us provide more useful suggestions.

Comment: Be sure to check your answer, otherwise if you are not sure it is more likely to be a comment.